# Кодировка Visual Studio Basic

Tags: visual-basic

Здравствуйте, проблема, на которой я сломал голову, заключается в том, что я хочу, чтобы шифровался текст, как в представленном ниже варианте кода. Указанный ниже код работает идеально. Но дело в том, что я хочу зашифрованный текст сохранить в файл, так чтобы потом можно было его из файла прочитать и расшифровать. И вот тут никак... Зашифрованный сохранил в виде текста, а обратно никак...
Люди добрые, вы такие умные, кто-нибудь подскажите хоть идею, а то просто тупик. За любые идеи заранее спасибо!

```
Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim unicodeString As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim encodedBytes() = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString)
    Dim b As Byte
    Label1.Text = ""
    For Each b In encodedBytes
        Label1.Text += Trim(Str(b))
    Next b
           Dim decodedString As String = utf8.GetChars(encodedBytes)
    Label2.Text += Trim(decodedString)
```

Comment: Это не шифрование, лучше назвать представлением строки в виде байтов в её кодировке. Вопрос сходится к тому, что вам надо сохранить и считать строку из файла?

Comment: Именно так, и упёрлось всё в то что обратно в буквы конвертация не получается. Методом utf8.GetChars(массив) ничего не выходит, происходит просто "копирование". Это сложная головоломка.
1)Из текста в encodedBytes() методом utf8.GetBytes(обычный текст) конвертирует в код.
2) Обратно utf8.GetChars(encodedBytes)  обратно в текст, тоже получается.
3)А вот если массив encodedBytes() выложить в файл( или текстовое поле), а потом обратно запихнуть в массив, то GetChars(encodedBytes) не работает. Всё так и остаётся в виде цифр.

Answer (score 1):

Массив байтов можно представить в виде строки можно через `String.Join()`:

```
Dim theBytes() As Byte = {30, 40, 50, 60}
Dim str As String = String.Join(" ", theBytes)
```

В обратную сторону: сначала получаем из строки массив строк с числами, потом парсим в массив байтов

```
Dim str As String = "12 23 34 45"
Dim strArray() As String = str.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim byteArray(strArray.Length) As Byte
For i As Integer = 0 To strArray.Length - 1
   byteArray(i) = Byte.Parse(strArray(i))
Next
```

В качестве разделителя между числами я выбрал пробел.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался наконец.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если Вы будете байтовое представление писать в таком виде, как в приведенном коде, то не сможете однозначно разбить полученную строку на байты. Попробуйте поставить пробелы  Label1.Text += (Trim(Str(b)) + " ") и декодировать строку ну например z0. Расставляйте разделители (те же пробелы) а дальше декодируйте в строку методом GetString

Comment: Нет, пробелы там и так автоматом компилятор подставляет, я пробовал, не помогает. И не понял по поводу z0, это что?
За совет спасибо.

Comment: Если в вашем коде в TextBox1 ввести строку z0 то в битовом виде получится 12248. Trim стирает пробелы. Обратно эту строку в байты как интерпретировать? 12 248? 12 24 8? об этом и речь была